# Can a function be simplified into real numbers?

Tags: functions

For the function $f(x)$:

$f(x) = \dfrac{(3x + |x|)}{x}$

Then simplify:

$f(x) = \dfrac{3x}{x} + \dfrac{|x|}{x}$

$f(x) = 3 + \dfrac{|x|}{x}$

$f(x) = 3 + \dfrac{x}{x}$ or $3 + \dfrac{(-x)}{x}$

$f(x) = 3 + 1$ or $3 - 1$

$f(x) = 4$ or $2$

I know I am doing something wrong because that function could not just become a number. What am I missing and how am I simplifying incorrectly ? Thanks.

Comment: You also have to notice that when you cancel $x/x$ or $(-x)/x$, you're assuming that $x\ne0$.

Comment: "function could not just become a number": why not ?

Comment: $f(x)=2$ is a function *simplified to real numbers*.

Answer (score 1):

The function is an indeterminate form for $x=0$.

Otherwise we can use the rule
$$\begin{cases}x\le 0\to|x|=-x,\\x\ge 0\to|x|=\ \ \ x\end{cases},$$ giving

$$\begin{cases}x<0\to f(x)=\dfrac{3x -x}{x}=2,\\x>0\to f(x)=\dfrac{3x +x}{x}=4.\end{cases}
$$

This is a piecewise constant function.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything wrong except not write your domains for the sides of the "or".

That function is equivalent to $f(x) = 4$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x<0$.